# Are there any diplomatic consequences for agreeing to unfavorable (to me) trade agreements?

Tags: civilization-5

If you propose to the AI a trade agreement which the AI perceives to be favorable to them, they will respond with things like "your offer is generous and I accept". In the attitude summary, however, I could not find anything that mentions these agreements.

Is there any diplomatic consequence for them? For example, if I give gifts to other civilizations, will it make future trade deals with them better for me, or will it dissuade them from attacking me, or make them approve of friendship requests, etc.?

Comment: Don't forget to consider that dealing with one civ may upset another civ - so it's not just about boosting relations with the civ in question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like this was updated in the June 2011 patch:

> [A diplomatic change] Track trades between players and allow that to positively influence relationships (the better the deal for the AI, the stronger the modifier). Particularly useful for bribing a hostile AI.

So it seems these sort of trade agreements do indeed have impact, at least since the patch.

Answer (score 6):

In my experience, yes, eventually.  There seem to be bonuses like "Our trade relations have been fair and forthright" or somesuch.  In practice I've always found this bonus rather hard to obtain however, and don't forget that dealing with one civ will often upset another civ - and that effect is much stronger.  Watch out!

Comment: @Glen You've seen that in Civ 5?  That sounds like Civ 4 to me, where it actually told you what was affecting diplomacu.

Comment: I didn't see it specifically, I just used familiar words for the mechanic at work.

Comment: @Glen So do you actually have proof that it works this way in Civ 5, or are you just basing it on how it worked in Civ 4?

Comment: @bwa I don't have any proof, I never saw the source code.  But I do have experience playing the game and it certainly seems to work in a similar way.  Are you saying you have proof that it doesn't work?  Then add another answer!

Comment: @Glen No, if I had evidence to the contrary I would post it. I agree that having trade agreements with people helps, I just don't know that I've ever seen something that leads me to believe that "generous" offers provide an additional bonus, and that is what the question is asking.

Comment: @bwa I've only ever noticed it for the "unfavourable" agreements.  Apparently these are either the only such things taken into account, or simply much more heavily weighted than other "fairer" agreements.  Perhaps in the future we will have better access to all of the game mechanics and we can see more precisely what is at work.  To make this more explicit, I've edited the answer.